# Table-per-type inheritance with the Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, poco

Is it possible to use the (awesome) [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator)  to generate POCOs in a [table-per-type](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) inheritance scenario?

My database contains a 'base' log table, and two tables that derive from it:

```
create table LogBase
(
    Id int identity(1, 1) not null,
    LogTime datetime not null default getdate(),
    constraint PK_LogBase primary key clustered(Id)
) 

create table ErrorLog
(
    Id int not null,
    ErrorMessage nvarchar(max),
    StackTrace nvarchar(max),
    constraint PK_ErrorLog primary key(Id),
    constraint FK_ErrorLog_LogBase foreign key(Id) references LogBase(Id)
)

create table ChangeLog
(
    Id int not null,
    PropertyName nvarchar(max),
    OldValue nvarchar(max),
    NewValue nvarchar(max),
    constraint PK_ChangeLog primary key(Id),
    constraint FK_ChangeLog_LogBase foreign key(Id) references LogBase(Id)
)
```

By default, the Reverse POCO Generator generates 3 C# classes - LogBase, ErrorLog, and ChangeLog - each of which contains an `Id` property, and which have no inheritance relationship with each other.

I can specify that ErrorLog and ChangeLog inherit from LogBase by creating the classes as partials and putting the `: LogBase` inheritance in the partial classes - **is this the correct way to specify the inheritance?**

In the template generator, the `UpdateColumn` callback allows me to specify tables that should omit their `Id` columns in the generated POCO.

I can use `UpdateColumn` for the ErrorLog and ChangeLog tables - this results in the 'Id' property being dropped from each class, which is correct for table-per-type inheritance.  However, it also results in the ErrorLog and ChangeLog classes being removed from the generated DbContext, and the following comment appears in the ErrorLog and ChangeLog classes:

```
// The table 'ChangeLog' is not usable by entity framework because it
// does not have a primary key. It is listed here for completeness.
```

- Is there a way to specify the inheritance relationship without
     causing the generator to omit the derived tables from the model?
- Is there a way of preventing the generator from including navigation
  properties in the generated POCOs?

Comment: Great pointer to the use of UpdateColumn to solve duplicate id issue in TPT. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release (5th Jan 2017) in v2.27 has fixed an issue (#167) with hidden columns and primary keys making this work now.

- Download v2.27 from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator
- Update your generator to the latest version (2.27 as of today)
- Re-add the generator to your project (to pick up the latest code) and re-implement your changes in the .tt file.
- Save the tt file.

Any problems, update the GitHub case over at https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/issues/181

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can work around it:

https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/issues/102

Comment: Many thanks @ErikEJ - a very useful link.  I've followed the advice, and while I've made some progress I'm still having issues - namely that the derived tables are prodicing POCOs with accompanying comments saying they 'are not usable by entity framework because they do not have a primary key'.  I've raised an issue in the GitHub project.